# Default value from related model

Tags: javascript, ajax, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I have a zip code table and a person table. When entering the persons zip I'll need the persons city-field to be filled with the city from the related zip table.

I'm starting to believe that this is something that cannot be done with Django. The solution will probably be jQuery/Ajax/JavaScript related.

models.py:

```py
from django.db import models

class Zip(models.Model):
    zipcode = models.IntegerField()
    city = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.zipcode)

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    zipcode =  models.ForeignKey('Zip',on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="zip_of_this_person")  
    personcity = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

forms.py

```py
from django import forms 
from .models import Zip, Person


class ZipForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Zip
        fields = ('zipcode', 'city',)
        


class PersonForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ('name', 'zipcode', 'personcity' )
```

views.py

```py
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from .forms import PersonForm, ZipForm
from .models import Zip, Person



# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'theapp/index.html' )

def person_new(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PersonForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.save()
            return redirect('person_detail', pk=post.pk)
        
    else:
        form = PersonForm()
    return render(request, 'theapp/person.html', {'form': form})

def zip_new(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ZipForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.save()
            return redirect('zip_detail', pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = ZipForm()
    return render(request, 'theapp/zip.html', {'form': form})

def person_detail(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Person, pk=pk)
    weather= "testing purposes"
    context= {
        'post': post,
        }
    return render(request, 'theapp/person_detail.html', context)

def zip_detail(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Zip, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'theapp/zip_detail.html', {'post': post})
```

And finally the html:

```
{% extends 'theapp/base/base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block title %}Tittel Tab{% endblock %}

{% block site_css %}{% endblock %}
{% block main_heading %}{% endblock %}   

{% block header_content %}{% endblock %}


{% block body %}
<section>
    <h2>Person</h2>
</section>

<article class="post">
    <h2>Name:{{ post.name }}</h2>
    <p>Zip/city:{{ post.zipcode }}{{ post.personcity }}</p>

        
</article>


{% endblock %}
```

So I have been searching all over and not really finding anything that helps me. I am not able to find any solution. If it was the other way around showing all related to that zip is quite easy.  I realize this is maybe a frontend issue and maybe not entirely a Django. But still it is pretty basic using a relational database.  Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can allow null and blank on personcity and then fill it when model is saved;
to do so you can go easy way and rewrite .save() method
smthing like this:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    zipcode =  models.ForeignKey('Zip',on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="zip_of_this_person")  
    personcity = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.personcity and self.zipcode and self.zipcode.city:
            self.personcity  = self.zipcode.personcity
        super(Person, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

or you can do this whith [pre_save signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/signals/#pre-save)